# how to use sed to delete a line if it has only one char

Tags: sed

File Pattern

```
      90      0.38085E+06        0.70466 -0.12552 -0.69836
               19901.            0.25991  0.96148  0.08944
              -13890.            0.66023 -0.24453  0.71014
1
      91      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
1
      92      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
```

I want to delete all 1's

Comment: Do you really mean **all** `1`s in file, or only `1`s which constitute single-character lines (as mentioned in title of your post)? You should be more specific. Also, have you tried anything? It's really not difficult to do that with `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

`sed '/^1$/d'` will do the trick.

`^` marks the beginning of the line, `$` marks the end of the line.  If the only thing on the line is a `1`, then the action is `d` (delete).  If you want to delete any line of length one, use the `.` wildcard instead of `1`.

**Example:**

```
$ cat test.txt
      90      0.38085E+06        0.70466 -0.12552 -0.69836
               19901.            0.25991  0.96148  0.08944
              -13890.            0.66023 -0.24453  0.71014
1
      91      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
1
      92      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776

$ cat test.txt | sed '/^1$/d'
      90      0.38085E+06        0.70466 -0.12552 -0.69836
               19901.            0.25991  0.96148  0.08944
              -13890.            0.66023 -0.24453  0.71014
      91      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
      92      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `sed` file

```
sed /^1/d
      90      0.38085E+06        0.70466 -0.12552 -0.69836
               19901.            0.25991  0.96148  0.08944
              -13890.            0.66023 -0.24453  0.71014
      91      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
      92      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
```

No quote needed for this `sed`

Using `awk`

```
awk '/^1/ {next}1' file
      90      0.38085E+06        0.70466 -0.12552 -0.69836
               19901.            0.25991  0.96148  0.08944
              -13890.            0.66023 -0.24453  0.71014
      91      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
      92      0.49423E+06       -0.66143 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.15942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.17395  0.65776
```

---

This will actually do what OP asks for, remove `1`

```
sed s/1//g
      90      0.38085E+06        0.70466 -0.2552 -0.69836
               990.            0.2599  0.9648  0.08944
              -3890.            0.66023 -0.24453  0.704

      9      0.49423E+06       -0.6643 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.5942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.7395  0.65776

      92      0.49423E+06       -0.6643 -0.04438  0.74870
               40374.           -0.5942  0.98375 -0.08253
              -25506.            0.73287  0.7395  0.65776
```

Comment: Can user who gave `-1` tell why?

Comment: Can't speak for that user, but it seems to me that your first solution deletes line beginning with `1`, even if containing more than 1 char; and your last `sed` proposal remove all `1`s from file, even if they're not the only character of a line, and even if they're in the middle of another number. Not sure it's what OP *really* wants.

Comment: @Qeole I guess its the starting `1`, but OP does write `I want to delete all 1's`, all is all....

Comment: I know. I wasn't the one who downvoted you. I asked for clarification to OP in the comments of the question, that would for sure help answering…